# Alternative to loading large file from s3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, nlp

I have been trying to load a large language model (> 5 GB) hosted on S3 for use in a Lambda function, but have been so far unsuccessful. The function just continuously times out after a few minutes, even when set on 10240 MB memory.

I assume this is because of the limits on the Lambda function, as well as the streaming of such a large file from S3.

For my implementation, my function needs to be able to load the language model fairly quickly ( ~5-10 seconds).

Being quite new to AWS, is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/mpuoverview.html - This is what you should be using for files that large. Also, not a good idea to use lambda for this use case.

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50105094/python-upload-large-files-s3-fast

Comment: You misunderstood the question, I'm not uploading a file to S3 using the Lambda, I'm trying to get an object from S3 for use in a Lambda function.

Comment: Yeah, I misunderstood. Probably this :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41776814/accessing-large-files-stored-in-aws-s3-using-aws-lambda-functions

Comment: How long does it take to load the model from your local disk, and how much memory does it occupy? It's possible that this is too big for a Lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the model in a EFs drive and then attach the efs to the lambda and you can do the calculations faster

https://aws.amazon.com/efs/